# Product with contractible space doesn't change the homotopy type

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the following question :

> If $X$ is contractible, then for any topological space $Y$, the
> product $X$ $×$ $Y$ has the same homotopy type of  $Y$.

Comment: Let $H\colon X\times [0,1]\to X$ be a homotopy from $\text{id}_X$ to a constant map $c\colon X\to *\in X$. Define $H_1\colon X\times Y\times [0,1]\to  X\times Y$ as follows: $$H_1(x,y,t):=\big(H(x,t),y\big)\text{ for all }(x,y,t)\in X\times Y\times [0,1].$$ Then $H_1(-,-,0)=\text{id}_{X\times Y}$ and $H_1(-,-,1)=i\circ \pi$, where $i\colon Y\ni y\longmapsto (*,y)\in X\times Y$ and $\pi\colon X\times Y\ni (x,y)\longmapsto y\in Y$.

Comment: Next, define $H_2\colon Y\times [0,1]\to Y$  as $$H_2(y,t):=y\text{ for all }(y,t)\in  Y\times [0,1].$$ Then, $H_2(-,0)=\text{id}_Y$ and $H_2(-,1)=\pi\circ i$. Thus, $i\colon Y\to X\times Y$ is a homotopy equivalence with homotopy inverse $\pi\colon X\times Y\to Y$.

Answer (score 1):

This chain of reasoning is correct. You're basically using the fact that (1) homeomorphic spaces are homotopy equivalent and (2) that homotopy equivalence is transitive. You are, however, glossing over the fact that $- \times Y$ preserves homotopy equivalence. It's not automatic that operations on topological spaces preserve homotopy type (this is the source of a great number of problems in homotopy theory), but it is true for $- \times Y$.

It's also reasonably straightforward to prove. To get you started, you may assume you're given maps $f : X \to X'$  and $g : X' \to X$ along with homotopies $H_0 : g \circ f \simeq 1$ and $H_1 : f \circ g \simeq 1$. You must produce a homotopy equivalence $X \times Y \simeq X' \times Y$. I'd suggest starting with the maps $f \times Y : X \times Y \to X' \times Y$ and $g \times Y : X' \times Y \to X \times Y$ and trying to lift $H_0$ and $H_1$.

Comment: @MarwaZeyad One can use $H_0$ and $H_1$ to produce homotopies witnessing the fact that $f \times Y$ and $g \times Y$ are homotopy inverses.

Comment: Yes. You'll need to show that $g \times Y \circ f \times Y$ is homotopic to the identity _and_ that $f \times Y \circ g \times Y$ is homotopic to the identity. You'll produce one of these homotopies with $H_0$ and the other with $H_1$.